# Why does Google Pagespeed have two different meaurements for First Contentful Paint (FCP)?

Tags: page-speed, load-time, google-pagespeed

I'm auditing the speed of some top pages on my site, and want to collect load time data so I can compare in the coming months.

I'm using PageSpeed Insights to measure my pages, but I'm confused because First Contentful Paint (FCP) is listed twice on the page, but with different recordings:

[image: Screenshot of PageSpeed insights]

Is there a reason why they're different?